# Downloading a pdf in webapp on iOS using iframe

Tags: ios, pdf, iframe

I am trying to download attachments in a webApp on iOS. I am using an iFrame for this. 

The iFrame's src points to a webservice which returns a byte array. I am setting the contenType as well.

Though this does not seem to work. I tried Safari as well as Chrome. I know that both the browsers can handle pdfs and iFrame works on iOS. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have control over the PDF source or is it a third-party?

Comment: Yepp, I do. Those are saved in the database.